# Building a Bootstrap table with dynamic elements in Flask

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, flask, sqlalchemy, bootstrap-table

I'm working with Flask on building a Bootstrap table out of a list of people taken from a SQLAlchemy database. However, the information I want to put in the table is appearing above it.

Here's the code in question:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block page_content %}
<div class="page-header">
    <h1>componentes familiares</h1>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <th>name</th>
                <th>age</th>
                <th>option</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for person in people %}
                    <tr>{{ person.name }}</tr>
                    <tr>{{ person.age }}</tr>
                    <tr>{{ person.option }}</tr>
                {% endblock %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
{% endblock %}
```

(This is already a slimmed-down version, since I kept taking stuff off to see if it would solve the problem.)

But let's say I have two persons in my database, Alice, and Bob. Alice is 30 and Bob is 40, Alice's option is 1 and Bob's is 2. This is what I get:

[image]

The information is there, but it's rendered above the table. And right below it comes the table header and an empty table row.

**Links**

I found another question about Bootstrap tables in Flask [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13315883/how-to-structure-data-to-easily-build-html-tables-in-flask), but it didn't really solve my problem. My data is being passed to the html page exactly as I want it, I just want to put it in a table.

I also found [Flask-Table](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Flask-Table), an extension to build the table in Python and then using it. It may end up being a solution, but I still don't see what's wrong with my code.

Didn't find anything useful in the [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables) either.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're missing a few `<tr>` and `<td>` tags:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>age</th>
            <th>option</th>
        <tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for person in people %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ person.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ person.age }}</td>
            <td>{{ person.option }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You're aiming for a table-row (`<tr>`) per user, and some table-data (`<td>`) for each of their attributes.  You've also got a `{% endblock %}` where you should have an `{% endfor %}`.

Comment: thanks a lot! I'm away from the computer now, but I'll fix my code tomorrow and I'm sure it's gonna work.