# How to display Python array in Datatables?

Tags: python, html, mysql, flask, datatables

I am using Flask, I have an array that I have read from a database, the array looks like [["customer", "address","PPL"], ["customer2", "address2","PPL2"]]

Using the DataTables plugin I want "customer" and "customer2" to display in the customer column, "address" and "address2" to display in the address column and "PPL" and "PPL2" in the PPL column. I can do this with a for loop in my HTML, but this messes up my DataTable formatting and removes the search box and prev/next buttons from the table. How can I get these value to populate the cells in the data table?

Python code:

```
def hello():

mariadb_connection = mariadb.connect(user='root', password='pwd', 
database='customers')
cursor = mariadb_connection.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT * from customer_info")
data = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.close()


namesdb = json.dumps(data)


return render_template('select_customer.html', namesdb=namesdb)
```

html:

```
<table id="example" class="table text-dark table-striped table-bordered 
  display" style="width:100%">

    <thead class="text-white">

        <tr>

            <th>Customer</th>

            <th>Address</th>

            <th>Price per Litre</th>


        </tr>

    </thead>

    <tbody>

    <tr>

            <td>{{namesdb}}</td>

            <td></td>

            <td></td>



        </tr>




    </tbody>

    <tfoot>

        <tr>



        </tr>

    </tfoot>

</table>

</div>
</div>
</div>

 </div>
</div>
```

I have been linked to this post, [How to structure data to easily build HTML tables in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13315883/how-to-structure-data-to-easily-build-html-tables-in-flask?noredirect=1&lq=1),

but as mentioned, using this for loop populates the columns in the DataTables table, but the for loop seems to remove the search box and prev/next buttons.

Script.js

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
 var table = $('#example').DataTable();
 $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
     $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  } );

 $('#button').click( function () {

alert( table.rows('.selected').data().length +' 
 row(s) selected' );

 } );

 } );
```

Comment: Can you also post your JS for the DataTables?

Comment: Hey jwebb, I have updated my post to include the datatables is at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one thing, don't json.dumps your data before sending it to the template.

```
def hello():

    mariadb_connection = mariadb.connect(user='root', password='pwd', 
    database='customers')
    cursor = mariadb_connection.cursor()

    cursor.execute("SELECT * from customer_info")
    namesdb = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()

    return render_template('select_customer.html', namesdb=namesdb)
```

Just use the pythonic list of tuples in Jinja.

```
{%- for item in namesdb -%}
<tr>
    <td>{{ item[0] }}</td>
    <td>{{ item[1] }}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
{%- endfor -%}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was trying to do! You have saved my laptop from being thrown through the window :-)